# Android activity is not changing after registering to the application successfully

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-volley

I have created an application that has a registration activity. When I click on the register button on the application, the user's details are inserted into the database but the activity will not change. For the login on the application, the activity changes from the login activity to the home activity as intended, but not for the register activity.

Here is the code:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                        Toast.makeText(register.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        btnRegister.setClickable(false);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(register.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } else if (response.equals("failure")) {
                        tvStatus.setText("Registration unsuccesful!");
                        Toast.makeText(register.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Just to be certain, you do see a toast appearing on the screen?

Comment: @SergioPardo The toast just before the `if statement` is appearing on the screen but not the toast inside the `if statement`. In other words, the code inside the `if statement` is not being executed.

Comment: What is the first toast showing?

Comment: @Christopher it is displaying the response which comes from a PHP API that I have created and working as expected. If the registration is successful then the API will return 'success' which is the case, else it will return 'failure'. The problem is that what is inside the if statement won't get executed for I don't know why.

Comment: Can you place here the response from the service? The string as it appears exactly on the toast. I feel like it could be something like you must compare ignoring upper case letters or some extra space on the text.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely to me that your response isn't what you expect, I haven't used the Listener you used but by looking at some other questions I found this:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
```

So please check if this works for you, instead of

```
if (response.equals("success")) {
```

this:

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");
if (success) {
}else{
}
```

You might need to add a try/catch around that.